# What namespace do I use to load a composer class in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, codeigniter-3

I am writing a composer package that I want to use in multiple CodeIgniter projects. Answers to that question can explain how to modify both package and application.

## The package

I created a composer package called `steevedroz/codeigniter-twig`. Its `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "steevedroz/codeigniter-twig",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "A simple CodeIgniter library that allows using Twig along with the usual CI helpers",
    "keywords": ["codeigniter", "twig"],
    "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/SteeveDroz/codeigniter-twig",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "SteeveDroz",
        "role": "Developer"
    }],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CodeigniterTwig\\": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

It contains a main class that I'd like to load from CodeIgniter, located at the root of the package. It's called `Twig.php` and contains:

```
<?php
namespace CodeigniterTwig;

class Twig {
    // ...
}
```

## The CodeIgniter project

My POC project is a basic CodeIgniter project with a `composer.json` file at the root (next to `application/`, `system/`, etc.) that contains:

```
{
    "require": {
        "steevedroz/codeigniter-twig": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I ran `composer install` that loaded my package correctly.

In `application/config.php`, I set:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] =  '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I one of my controllers, I'd like to load my `Twig` class as a library like this:

```
$this->load->library('CodeigniterTwig/twig');
```

But when I check the result, I get the error:

```
Unable to load the requested class: Twig
```

I tried with different namespaces (see below), but the result is always the same!

- `steevedroz/CodeigniterTwig/twig`
- `CodeigniterTwig/twig`
- `twig`
- `steevedroz/codeigniter-twig/twig`

I guess the problem has to do with namespaces.

Any clue?

Comment: You should use `psr-4` instead of `psr-0`.

Comment: No problem, I'm open, I just found a tutorial for PSR-0, that's why I used it. Feel free to explain your solution with PSR-4 if you have one!

Comment: This must be really weird tutorial, because you've created class using PSR-4 convention and then defined autoloading using `psr-0` rules. Try replace `psr-0` by `psr-4` in your `composer.json`.

Comment: Done, I edit the question.